# Bean property 'transactionManagerBeanName' is not writable or has an invalid setter method

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to configure Spring3 + JPA using Hibernate, but I am getting an exception while spring tries to create a Bean called TransactionInterceptor, the exception is attached. Any help is welcome. I am sending my app-config.xml, my persistence.xml and the error stack trace below:

**My app-config.xml**

```
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
 xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
 xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
 xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd">

 <context:component-scan base-package="com.mypackage" />

 <task:annotation-driven executor="myExecutor"
  scheduler="myScheduler" />

 <task:executor id="myExecutor" pool-size="5" />

 <task:scheduler id="myScheduler" pool-size="10" />

 <context:load-time-weaver />

 <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
  class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
  <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="MyPersistenceUnit" />
 </bean>

 <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
  <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
 </bean>
 <bean
  class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

 <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
</beans>
```

Here is my persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0"
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
 <persistence-unit name="MyPersistenceUnit"
  transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

  <!-- org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl -->
  <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

  <properties>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class"
    value="org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider" />
   <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
   <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
   <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="3" />
   <property name="hibernate.query.factory_class"
    value="org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory" />
   <property name="hibernate.query.substitutions" value="true 1, false 0" />
   <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
   <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
   <property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="MYDATABASE" />

   <!-- Use the C3P0 connection pool. -->
   <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="10" />
   <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="25" />
   <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="600" />
   <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="15" />
   <property name="hibernate.connection.url"
    value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MYDATABASE?autoReconnect=true&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf-8" />
   <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root" />
   <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="root" />

   <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class"
    value="net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheProvider" />
   <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true" />
   <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache"
    value="true" />
   <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true" />

  </properties>

 </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**Here is the exception:**

```
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0': Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'transactionManagerBeanName' of bean class [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor]: Bean property 'transactionManagerBeanName' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1361)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:442)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:339)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:306)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
 at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1173)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:809)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:615)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
 at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.NormalRewrittenUrl.doRewrite(NormalRewrittenUrl.java:195)
 at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:159)
 at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:141)
 at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:90)
 at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:417)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
 at com.springsource.insight.collection.tcserver.request.HttpRequestOperationCollectionValve.invoke(HttpRequestOperationCollectionValve.java:60)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:379)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:637)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'transactionManagerBeanName' of bean class [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor]: Bean property 'transactionManagerBeanName' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
 at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:1038)
 at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:914)
 at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:76)
 at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:58)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358)
 ... 42 more
Aug 31, 2010 1:04:27 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
```

Comment: do you have `transactionManagerBeanName` in any of your spring xml files?

Comment: no I don't but .. Do you have one in your JPA + Spring app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [TransactionInterceptor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionInterceptor.html) does not contain a setter for the transactionManagerBeanName, only for the Transaction manager instance and the transaction attributes.

Comment: Yeah, but i have never touched on this class.

Comment: What hell Spring is trying to set this property in this class?

Comment: Very strange, got a new pom.xml from on example project (spring + jpa) and I could get it working. Seems that some dependency was missing.

Comment: @Thiago I know its old but i am geting same same exception anyway you can post pom.xml ?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem and (I think) have tracked it down to a dependencies problem.

I'm using org.springframework/spring-tx/3.0.3.RELEASE for transactions, and I had been trying to use org.springframework/spring-hibernate/1.2.9 for the hibernate bindings. This was causing grief (I think) because the JARs contained incompatible versions of the TransactionInterceptor class (according to Eclipse).

Now that I have switched to org.springframework/spring-hibernate3/2.0.8 the problem seems to have gone away.  There are still two versions of the class, but they appear to be compatible.

**UPDATE**

Actually, the correct module for the hibernate3 support classes for Spring 3.0.x seems to be:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Very strange, got a new pom.xml from on example project (spring + jpa) and I could get it working. Seems that some dependency was missing.

Comment: Why don't you elaborate more your answer and show what libs you were missing or if there were a conflict in the libs you had? And at last mark the answer as accepted.