# Spring IllegalStateException: A JTA EntityManager cannot use getTransaction()

Tags: java, spring, websphere

So after a big refactoring project, I am left with this exception and am unsure as how to correct it. It's dealing with some code that I did not write and I am unfamiliar with how it all works. There are other questions out there dealing with this exception, but none seem to fit my situation.

The class which uses `EntityManager` is `SpecialClaimsCaseRepositoryImpl`:

```
package com.redacted.sch.repository.jpa;

//Imports

@Repository
public class SpecialClaimsCaseRepositoryImpl extends SimpleJpaRepository<SpecialClaimsCaseDto, SpecialClaimsCaseDto.Id> implements SpecialClaimsCaseRepository{

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "schManager")
    private EntityManager em;

          //Some autogenerated methods

    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }

    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }
}
```

Persistence.xml:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.0">

    <persistence-unit name="schManager">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/SCH_DS</jta-data-source>
        <class>com.redacted.sch.domain.model.SpecialClaimsCaseDto</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.WebSphereExtendedJTATransactionLookup" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="com.bcbsks.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.jdbc.use_scrollable_resultset" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

sch_model_spring.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

        <context:component-scan base-package="com.redacted.repository.jpa,
              com.redacted.sch.domain.model,
              com.redacted.sch.repository.jpa,
              com.redacted.sch.service,
              com.redacted.sch.service.impl"/>

        <tx:annotation-driven />

        <tx:jta-transaction-manager />

        <!-- Data source used for testing -->
        <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver" />
            <property name="url" value="jdbc:db2:redacted.redacted.com" />
            <property name="username" value="redacted" />
            <property name="password" value="redacted" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
              <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="schManager" />
              <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
            <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
        </bean> 
</beans>
```

And here's my project structure:

[image]

>

Here's a portion of the stack trace, with the full trace at this [fpaste](http://fpaste.org/117413/14051058/)

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A JTA EntityManager cannot use getTransaction()
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.getTransaction(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:985)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.DefaultJpaDialect.beginTransaction(DefaultJpaDialect.java:67)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:380)
    ... 80 more
```

I'm a total noob here, so if any other information is needed just ask and I'll update.

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Do you need to use the WebSphereExtendedJTATransactionLookup? Maybe you could switch to JPA Transactions via Spring?

Comment: Do you try to do some manual transactional magic? Your WebSphere will use a transaction while calling methods in your @Repository. Either already existing ones or it will create a new transaction.

Comment: Post the configuration of your transaction manager. Judging from your exceptions I suspect you are using the `JpaTransactionManager` instead of the appropriate Jta transactionmanager.

Comment: Added. Looks like you're right, I am using JpaTransactionManager. Not sure what it should be, @flob's suggestion also did not work.

Comment: See my answer, it basically depends on what you need. However could you please add the configuration of your entitymanager and transaction manager in spring.

Comment: You want to use JTA but in your configuration do everything to prevent that. For production use jta and a jndi-lookup for the datasource, for local/test use jpa en a direct datasource. For this you can use spring profiles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is your configuration. You have hibernate configured for JTA.

```
<property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.WebSphereExtendedJTATransactionLookup" />
```

Whereas you are using local transactions instead of distributed transactions.

```
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:380)
```

You have 2 possible solutions

1. remove the `JpaTransactionManager` and replace it with a JTA transaction manager
2. remove the remove the `hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class` from the hibernate settings.

If you don't really need distributed transactions option 2 is the easiest, if you need distributed transactions simply adding `<tx:jta-transaction-manager />` will setup a proper JTA tx manager for your environment. Remove the definition for the `JpaTransactionManager`.

**Update:**

Your configuration is flawed in 2 ways.

1. Your EntityManager configuration already contains a jndi lookup for the datasource, which you override in your applicationContext by configuring a local datasource
2. You have both a `<tx:jta-transaction-manager />` and `JpaTransactionManager` which one do you want to use? At the moment the latter is overriding the first one.

Create 2 seperate configurations one for local testing and one for production using JTA en JNDI lookups. (Preferable your testing code only overrides the beans necessary).

Comment: Well, for testing purposes I have a local copy of a test database. But for production, distributed transactions will be used, so that configuration will need to stay? I don't quite understand what you say needs done for keeping distributed transactions.

Comment: Alright just deleting that JpaTransactionManager bean seems to have fixed this issue, thought it has just opened up a new error yet again... The joys of being handed code by a person who then leaves...

Answer (score 1):

Use `WebSphereTransactionManagerLookup` for the transaction manager lookup in Hibernate

```
<property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.WebSphereTransactionManagerLookup" />
```

and remove your current transaction manager and replace it with the `WebSphereUowTransactionManager`.

```
<tx:annotation-driven/>
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager"/>
```

for your transaction manager lookup in Spring.

See  [IBM Websphere](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7JFU_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/cspr_data_access_tran1.html?lang=en) and  [Spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-application-server-integration-websphere) docs
 for more in depth documentation.

Comment: This does not work. Returns a NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'entityManagerFactory of bean class [org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager]

Comment: Do you have spring-orm in your classpath? See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4385222/510711)

Comment: Yup spring-orm 4.0.0 is in my dependency hierarchy.

Comment: Maybe the documentation from  [Spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-application-server-integration-websphere)
and [IBM Websphere](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7JFU_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/cspr_data_access_tran1.html?lang=en) help to see some subtle errors you made?